# Generating documentation using Maven openapi-generator-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, openapi-generator

I would like to use the Maven openapi-generator-maven-plugin to generate documentations in html format from my documentations in yaml-format. I manage to generate the documentation when I configure the plugin in the individual module´s pom.xml like so:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
        <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>openapi-html</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/docs/v2022.05.yaml</inputSpec>
                    <generatorName>html2</generatorName>
                    <output>${project.build.directory}/site/api</output>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

Is there a way to instruct Maven to generate html-files from all yaml-files in the docs folder without specifying the filenames? I have about ten yaml-files in each docs folder so that would save me a lot of repetitive code.

Maybe there even is a way to configure the plugin in the parent pom.xml only? The folder structure is the equal among all modules so that might be possible too.

```
parent
    +- module1
        +- src
        +- docs
        +- target
        pom.xml
    +- module2
        +- src
        +- docs
        +- target
        pom.xml
    +- module3
        +- src
        +- docs
        +- target
        pom.xml
    pom.xml
```